# ember cli build fingerprinting external URL?

Tags: ember.js

I have this route podcasts. The model hook calls getJSON to a url on a different domain. 
When I build for production, ember-cli seems to think this is an asset and fingerprints it like so:

```
http://datafruits.streampusher.com/podcasts/datafruits-d31215e1fe906877c93d6ac2208c8da2.json
```

I tried adding it to the exclude property in the fingerprint option in ember-cli-build.js, but I seem to get the same result. I tried the full URL as well.

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    fingerprint: {
      exclude: ['datafruits.json']
    }
  });
```

Yes my app is called "datafruits" if that has anything to do with it.
Here is the aforementioned podcasts route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      Ember.$("#podcastsModal").modal('hide');
    }
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function () {
      Ember.$("#podcastsModal").modal('show');
      var _this = this;
      Ember.$("#podcastsModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log("modal exited");
        _this.transitionTo('application');
      });
    });
  },

  model: function(){
    return Ember.$.getJSON('http://datafruits.streampusher.com/podcasts/datafruits.json')
    .then(function(data){
      return data.podcast;
    });
  }
```

The rest of my ember-cli-build.js:

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var ES6Modules = require('broccoli-es6modules');
var esTranspiler = require('broccoli-babel-transpiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    fingerprint: {
      //prepend: "//datafruitstest.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/",
      exclude: ['datafruits.json']
    }
  });

  // Use `app.import` to add additional libraries to the generated
  // output files.
  //
  // If you need to use different assets in different
  // environments, specify an object as the first parameter. That
  // object's keys should be the environment name and the values
  // should be the asset to use in that environment.
  //
  // If the library that you are including contains AMD or ES6
  // modules that you would like to import into your application
  // please specify an object with the list of modules as keys
  // along with the exports of each module as its value.
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/moment/moment.js');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/jplayer/dist/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/jsTimezoneDetect/jstz.min.js');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/emojione/assets/css/emojione.css');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/emojione/lib/js/emojione.js');
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/autolink/autolink.js');

  var phoenixTree = "./vendor/phoenix";
  var phoenixAmdFiles = new ES6Modules(phoenixTree, {
    format: 'amd',
    esperantoOptions: {
      strict: true,
      amdName: "phoenix"
    }
  });
  var phoenixTranspiledFiles = esTranspiler(phoenixAmdFiles, {});

  return mergeTrees([app.toTree(), phoenixTranspiledFiles]);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`broccoli-asset-rev`](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev) library that does the fingerprinting seems to want excluded filenames without the extension. If you use the following, it should build without fingerprinting `datafruits.json`:

```
fingerprint: {
  //prepend: "//datafruitstest.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/",
  exclude: ['datafruits']
}
```

Comment: This does work, but now my app JS is not fingerprinted because my app is called "datafruits". :(

Comment: [Looking at their tests](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev/blob/master/tests/filter-tests.js#L94) , it may be a bug. I'd report it at least to see if it's truly something not working with the lib.

Comment: So looking further, I believe this is an issue with [`broccoli-asset-rewrite`](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rewrite), where it is not accounting for the fact that the file is not the same one as the app JS (which should be fingerprinted). It doesn't appear to be taking the full file path into consideration when renaming the paths.

Comment: Just reported the issue here: https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rewrite/issues/24

Comment: Nice! I'll be following the issue. :)